# Dúvidas sobre a linguagem OCL

Tags: ocl

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Salvo o engano, imagino que a resposta seja algo como:

context Pessoa:: calculaTotalRendimentos(): Integer
body:

Infelizmente não sei como obter acesso a todos os empregos de uma pessoa e somar seus ganhos, também não achei tantos materiais bons na internet que pudessem tirar minhas dúvidas, salvo alguns pdfs em inglês. Caso tenham links  que possam ajudar no entendimento de OCL agradeço bastante!